# Why should pop() take an argument?

Tags: java, c++, stack

**Quick background**
I'm a Java developer who's been playing around with C++ in my free/bored time.

**Preface**
In C++, you often see pop taking an argument by reference:

```
void pop(Item& removed);
```

I understand that it is nice to "fill in" the parameter with what you removed.  That totally makes sense to me.  This way, the person who asked to remove the top item can have a look at what was removed.

However, if I were to do this in Java, I'd do something like this:

```
Item pop() throws StackException;
```

This way, after the pop we return either: NULL as a result, an Item, or an exception would be thrown.

My C++ text book shows me the example above, but I see plenty of stack implementations taking no arguments ([stl stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/pop/) for example).

**The Question**
How should one implement the pop function in C++?

**The Bonus**
Why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To answer the question: you should not implement the pop function in C++, since it is already implemented by the STL.  The [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) container adapter provides the method `top` to get a reference to the top element on the stack, and the method `pop` to remove the top element.  Note that the `pop` method alone cannot be used to perform both actions, as you asked about.

Why should it be done that way?

1. **Exception safety:** Herb Sutter gives a good explanation of the issue in [GotW #82](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/082.htm).
2. **Single-responsibility principle:** also mentioned in GotW #82.  `top` takes care of one responsibility and `pop` takes care of the other.
3. **Don't pay for what you don't need:** For some code, it may suffice to examine the top element and then pop it, without ever making a (potentially expensive) copy of the element.  (This is mentioned in the [SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stack.html#3) documentation.)

Any code that wishes to obtain a copy of the element can do this at no additional expense:

```
Foo f(s.top());
s.pop();
```

Also, [this discussion](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35709312/standard-library-pop.aspx) may be interesting.

If you were going to implement pop to return the value, it doesn't matter much whether you return by value or write it into an out parameter.  Most compilers implement [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), which will optimize the return-by-value method to be just as efficient as the copy-into-out-parameter method.  Just keep in mind that either of these will likely be less efficient than examining the object using top() or front(), since in that case there is absolutely no copying done.

Comment: Awesome links, thank you much.  So, if I'm asked in an interview to implement pop() in C++... should I give them your answer?  :p

Comment: +1… but maybe "if you implement the pop function in C++, you should follow the standard container interface."

Comment: @Stephano: Depends what the interviewer wants.  Some may be satisfied that you know about `std::stack` and know it has `push`, `top`, and `pop` methods.  Some may want you to implement your own stack using a fixed-length array, just to see if you can do it.

Comment: BTW a good follow-up question, if an interviewee mentioned `std::stack`, would be to ask what kind of underlying container is used in that adaptor and why it is a good choice.

Comment: @Dan: you should make clear in the answer that the `std::stack::pop()` has a different interface than in the question (ie., that `pop()` on;y adjusts the container, it doesn't return the top element either as a rturn value or via a passed in reference).

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the Java approach is that its `pop()` method has at least two effects: removing an element, and returning an element. This violates the single-responsibility principle of software design, which in turn opens door for design complexities and other issues. It also implies a performance penalty.

In the STL way of things the idea is that sometimes when you `pop()` you're not interested in the item popped. You just want the effect of removing the top element. If the function returns the element and you ignore it then that's a wasted copy.

If you provide two overloads, one which takes a reference and another which doesn't then you allow the user to choose whether he (or she) is interested in the returned element or not. The performance of the call will optimal.

The STL doesn't overload the `pop()` functions but rather splits these into two functions: `back()` (or `top()` in the case of the `std::stack` adapter) and `pop()`. The `back()` function just returns the element, while the `pop()` function just removes it.

Comment: A function that has two effects as a single atomic operation does not violate the single-responsibility principle of software design.

Comment: @Dave how many reasons are there to change for a function `pop()` that removes and returns an element? If you can count more than one then it violates the single-responsibility principle.

Comment: @Wilhelm - a requirement of `pop()` for some queue implementations in Java is that it does the two actions **atomically**.

Comment: The single-responsibility principle concerns the responsibility of classes or components in your system, not the effects of the methods. You can take design principles too far, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++0x makes the whole thing hard again.

As

```
stack.pop(item); // move top data to item without copying
```

makes it possible to efficiently move the top element from the stack. Whereas

```
item = stack.top(); // make a copy of the top element
stack.pop(); // delete top element
```

doesn't allow such optimizations.

Comment: `item = std::move(stack.top()); stack.pop();` does work efficiently however. The interesting thing to note is that the primary reason for this design in C++03 (exception safety) is no longer the case in C++11 (because move constructors should be no-throw).

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see for using this syntax in C++:

```
void pop(Item& removed);
```

is if you're worried about unnecessary copies taking place.

if you return the `Item`, it *may* require an additional copy of the object, which *may* be expensive.

In reality, C++ compilers are very good at copy elision, and almost always implement return value optimization (often even when you compile with optimizations disabled), which makes the point moot, and may even mean the simple "return by value" version becomes *faster* in some cases.

But if you're into premature optimization (if you're *worried* that the compiler might not optimize away the copy, even though in practice it *will* do it), you might argue for "returning" parameters by assigning to a reference parameter.

More information [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, a good signature for the eqivalent of Java's `pop` function in C++ would be something like:

```
boost::optional<Item> pop();
```

Using option types is the best way to return something that may or may not be available.