# How do I use a priority queue in c++?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

For example we have `priority_queue<int> s;` which contains some elements. What will be correct form of the following code:

```
while (!s.empty()) {
    int t=s.pop();// this does not retrieve the value from the queue
    cout<<t<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work" ? And how is `s` defined ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But queues usually have queue or list semantics (First in First Out), using methods like "enqueue/dequeue" or "offer/poll" instead of push/pop, which are stack semantics (Last in first out). (Some priority queues are modeled with the help of stacks, though, so it would help to know what you're trying to do).

Comment: Formatting is worth 100 words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to your documentation and you'll see `pop` has no return value. There are [various reasons for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756233/why-should-pop-take-an-argument/2756265#2756265), but that's another topic.

The proper form is:

```
while (!s.empty())
{
    int t = s.top();
    s.pop();

    cout << t << endl;
}
```

Or:

```
for (; !s.empty(); s.pop())
{
    cout << s.top(); << endl;
}
```